# How to make editable roles in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to make Role-based authorization using ASP.NET Core, but roles need to be editable. My idea is to make roles like this:

- name
- canEdit
- canDelete
- etc.

And the user would have assigned role.

Default roles are not an option, because I need to edit those roles.
I'm thinking about some weird using of **Policies** or writing my own authorization.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] // Not editable
```

I have to tell, that I'm not using `Identity` and for authentication I have JWT.

---

```
...
[Authorize(Policy = "CanEdit")]
SomeEditMethod()
...
```

---

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CanEdit", policy => policy.RequirePrivilege("CanEdit"));
    });
}
```

I can be hard to make `RequirePrivilege`.
What do you think fellows developers? Any ideas?

Comment: What's your question? Do you want Claims based authorization?

Comment: Did you try System.Security.Claims? You could use IClaimsTransformation  to transform from your "role based system" to claims.

Comment: Claims are hard to maintain I guess. If I understand this right, every user has his own Claims. @Briefkasten suggested nice idea. I will try it!

Comment: So... Do I need to store my transformed Claims in JWT?

Comment: @Morasiu Not necessary. You could save your transformed claims back to your "role based system". This way you could load and save claims.

Comment: What do you mean by "roles need to be editable"? Explain what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I mean, that I need to have some feature (ultimately by frontend) to edit, add and delete roles. Some kind of endpoint, which will allow to manipulate role rights like canEdit, canDelete etc.

Comment: It's a little unclear of what you need exactly, but you could also look at [Authorization filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#authorization-filters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so...

I did it by saving this in JWT, and then adding policies like this.

```
  ...
  services.AddAuthorization(options => {
     options.AddPolicy("CanEditUnit", policy => policy.RequireClaim("CanEditUnit", "True"));
  });
  ...
```

And them using `Authorize` attribute. For example:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "CanEditUnit")
```

Thanks everyone for help! Especially @Briefkasten.